# How to use an image having imaginary values for further processing like binarization in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, gesture-recognition, complextype, binary-image, homomorphic-filter

I have a gray image on which I have applied homomorphic filtering. The result of this filtering gives me an image which has some complex numbers as it's pixel values. When I viewed imaginary image and real image separately, then I realized I need only imaginary image for further processing. But I am unable to use it as I am unable to binarize the imaginary image for further processing. 
If anyone has any solution or suggestion regarding this then kindly let me know.

Here is the whole process image:[image]

complex image: [image]

real image: [image]

original gray image: [image]

Comment: Take the imaginary part and apply a threshold?

Comment: I tried using imbinarize in MATLAB but it is saying that cannot binarize and image having imaginary values. I tried selecting min value out of imaginary values but could not find as it is giving error.

Comment: How where you able to plot the imaginary part? You probably used `imag`. Use the output, which is real, as argument for `imbinarize`. You can also apply a threshold manually by using an equality comparision, i.e. `image > thresholdValue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like m7913d says, you can take the imaginary part of each pixel by using `imag`:

Ex:

```
imaginary_img = imag(complex_img);
```

Besides that, a good technique to binarize is set the threshold using the mean of image.

```
threshold = mean(mean(imaginary_img));
binarized_img = imbinarize(imaginary_img,threshold);
```